# How to run @BeforeClass multiple times

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests, testng

I have one basetest class in which I have written the code for instantiating the browser  using the singelton pattern

```
public class BaseTest {
    public static  WebDriver driver;
    @BeforeClass(alwaysRun=true,groups={"dependx"})
    public static  WebDriver setBrowser()// double checked login using synchronized keyword will increase the time by 100
    {
        if(driver==null){
            synchronized(BaseTest.class){
                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/home/user/Downloads/driver/chromedriver");
                 driver = new ChromeDriver();   
            }
        }
        return driver;
    }
}
```

Now my code is running is sucessfully till I close the browser using quit or close method 
Now the 2nd time when I am re-executing the same code its giving me

nosuchSession exception

here is my TestClass

```
public class SimpleBase1 {
    public SimpleBase1() {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }

    SimpleBase2 obj;
    FullLafdefy obj2;
    public WebDriver driver = BaseTest.setBrowser();

    @FindBy(xpath ="//a[@id ='yourRooms']/span[contains(text(),'Rooms: ')]")
    WebElement cartButton;
    @FindBy(xpath ="//a[@id='aLamps']")
    WebElement Lamps;

    @BeforeClass
    public void before(){
        obj = new SimpleBase2(driver);
        obj2 = new FullLafdefy(driver);
    }
    @Test(priority=1)
    public void navigateToSite(){
        System.out.println("Here it is  "+Constants.url.value);
        FullLafdefy.navigateToUrl(driver, Constants.returnUrl());
        System.out.println("pretty Please ");
    }

    @AfterClass
    public void tearDown(){
        driver.close();
        driver=null;
    }
}
```

Everything works fine upto this and  I want to ensure the driver value should be equal to null so I inserted one extra line "driver=null;" after this

Now In my 2nd testClass

```
public class SignPageTest {
    public WebDriver driver = BaseTest.setBrowser();
    SignPage obj ;
    Boolean stu;


    @Test
    public void navigateToSignPage(){
    obj = new SignPage(driver);
    stu = obj.navigateToSignIn();
    }
    @Test(priority=2)
    public void getHandles(){
        stu = obj.handlingWindows();
    }

}
```

here is my testNG.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
    <test name="Test1">
    <classes>
          <class name="TestPackageClasses.BaseTest"/>
          <class name="trialPackage.SimpleBase1"/>  
    </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="Test2">
    <classes>
         <class name="TestPackageClasses.BaseTest"/>
         <class name="TestPackageClasses.SignPageTest"/> 
    </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Can someone please tell me how to re-execute the code of @BeforeClass or it maybe @BeforeTest multiple times

Comment: I am able to execute the same sort of  framework  using appium

Comment: Any reason you are placing tests in pageobjects (SimpleBase1)?

Comment: Thats a whole another idea I want to Send my webElements as parameter  to another methods in my page class , I just want to re-use it 
But in that I was getting null pointer as the value of the webElement was null

Can you please show me your way on how you re-instantiate your browser  after closing or quiting it

Comment: You are setting the instance variable driver of the class SimpleBase1 to null and not the static class variable driver of the class BaseTest. Use this BaseTest.driver = null instead. It is never a good idea to mix pageobjects and tests. Also look at the access modifiers everything is public or package. What is the purpose of singelton? The setBrowser() method has a BeforeClass annotation, this will never get fired by testNg unless there are tests inside that class. Anyways you are calling it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

I see a lot of issues with your code. Here are a few :

1. Your singleton approach is a recipe to disaster if at all you decide to start running your tests in parallel. I would suggest that change it to either a Factory method which when invoked will produce a webdriver instance. So your tests can directly invoke the factory method and work with the webdriver.
2. Your singleton is annotated using `@BeforeClass` but nowhere in your code you are leveraging the `@BeforeClass` annotation capabilities because none of your test classes are extending `BaseTest`. So you can very well get rid of this annotation in this class.
3. Your suite xml is explicitly referring to `BaseTest`. This causes the `@BeforeClass` to run. But the second `<test name="Test2">` is what goofs it up because your test class `TestPackageClasses.SignPageTest` is basically querying `BaseTest.setBrowser()` via a class level data member. What this means is that, the call to `setBrowser()` will happen as soon as TestNG creates an instance for `SignPageTest`. TestNG instantiates the test class much before, and only later does it invoke `@BeforeClass`.

So here are some quick fixes to your code.

1. Have all your test classes extend `BaseTest`. That way they don't need to do anything extra to get hold of the webdriver object because its readily available from the base class. The instantiation of the webdriver logic can still be part of your `@BeforeClass` method. But remember that doing this will seriously limit your ability to run tests in parallel. If you would like to do it at a method level and also be ready for parallelism, you would need to use `@BeforeMethod` + `ThreadLocal` (or) use TestNG listeners. You can read more about it in my blog post [here](https://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2013/07/31/parallel-webdriver-executions-using-testng/)
2. Remove off all your synchronization logic and the singleton approach from your `BaseTest` class.